# Issues wiith libssh cross-compilation for ARM

Tags: zlib, beagleboneblack, libssh

I am trying to cross compile libssh for ARM on a beaglebone black, following error happens when I run then 'make' command:

```
[ 52%] Linking CXX executable libsshpp_noexcept
../src/libssh.so.4.5.1: undefined reference to `deflateInit_'
```

I already run the cmake command with paths for libz and other arm gcc compiler paths, still facing the above error.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve this issue by rebuilding the correct arm version of zlib and re-installing it. Also using the ccmake GUI utility I removed the examples compilation which was creating other examples related errors. The correct installation of libssh requires, openssl, zlib, libzip all compiled for the same target arch as libssh.

Comment: I have been unable to cross compile libssh.  From looking at the logs it appears that no matter what I tell it to use it always chooses the local compiler instead of the cross-compiler.  If you know how to get it to use the cross compiler I'd appreciate the help.